# A.s. Constant conditional expectation equals expectation a.s.?

Tags: probability

I just came across something that I didn't notice before about conditional expectation - Is this correct:

If $Z = \text{const. a.s.}$, then $Z=\mathbb{E}[X]$ a.s.,

where
$Z = \mathbb{E}[X \mid \mathcal{A}]$ for a random variable $X$ and a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}?

(I would conclude this from the property $\mathbb{E}[ X 1_A] = \mathbb{E}[Z 1_A]$, where for $Z(\omega) = z$ a.s., $A=\Omega$ I get $\mathbb{E}[X] = z$ a.s.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if $Z$ is constant almost surely, then certainly this constant will be $\mathbb E[Z]$.

In other words, you can choose $X=Z$ and $\mathcal A$ as the given $\sigma$-algebra.